# What's the difference between a functional and a technical change?

Tags: terminology

Example:

> We need to alter this software program, due to a **functional change**
>   asked by the system administrator.
>
> We need to alter this software program, due to a **technical change**
>   asked by the system administrator.

I would say a **functional change** occurs when a new function is asked and a **technical change** occurs when a different technical solution is proposed, to implement an existing function.

I know *functional/technical change* are not universal "terms", but can anyone give me an insight on what they are?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of the terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A functional change would be driven by a change to the functional requirements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement. e.g. The software needs to provide an additional field in a report it generates.

A technical change would be driven by a change to the non-functional requirements of the system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement. e.g. The database the software uses is being upgraded to a new version